# @import error while building sqlite.swift in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite.swift

I am new to iOS development. I am working on developing an app which saves data into a sqlite.swift db and I have added the SQLite framework to the targets and linked the required libraries as per the manual installation process of https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift. But there is an error with the following message while building:

> '@import' in framework header is discouraged, including this header requires -fmodules..

This is in the sqlite.h file.
Here is the file detail:

```
@import Foundation;

FOUNDATION_EXPORT double SQLiteVersionNumber;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char SQLiteVersionString[];
```

Comment: iOS comes with SQLite support. There's no need to build it yourself.

Comment: yes but we need the framework and binaries right? import sqlite doesnt work without that..i was getting error without the sqlite frameworks

Comment: No you don't need anything except `import SQLite3` in any Swift file that you want to write SQLite code in.